# Android Push Notification - How to get notification data when you click on action button of individual push notification

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, push-notification

Plugin Used -[Cordova Push Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)

There are two button "Accept" and "Ignore" When i am sending push

I want to identify which notification is clicked and

I want to get notification data When App comes in foreground mode By click on Action of individual notification

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Open File GCMIntentService.java from given below directory

plugins\phonegap-plugin-push\src\android\com\adobe\phonegap\push

2) Replace line from Old To New
Old : createActions(extras, mBuilder, resources, packageName, notId);

New : createActions(extras, mBuilder, resources, packageName, notId,requestCode);

3) Replace line from Old To New
Old : private void createActions(Bundle extras, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, Resources resources, String packageName, int notId)

New : private void createActions(Bundle extras, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, Resources resources, String packageName, int notId,int requestCode)

4) Replace line from Old To New
Old : pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

New : pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

5) Replace line from Old To New
Old : pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

New : pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);